# Pandas record_path for multiple array in JSON data

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, group-by

How can I read a nested JSON file in a pandas dataframe?. I tried with `pd.json_normalize(results,record_path=` option but unable to get *auto_scan_date*. i just want to understand path and help in this case.

here below the bit sample JSON content

```
[{
  "owner": "admin@123",
  "ipadd": "10.10.10.10",
  "servername": "demoserver1.admin.com",
  "Status": "live",
  "config": [
    {
      "ipadd": "10.10.10.10",
      "scan": {
        "last_scan_date": "2000-10-10 23:53",
        "auto_scan": [
            {
            "auto_scan_date": "2000-10-11 23:53" 
            }
            ],
        "scan_status": "Enable",
        "enable_datetime": "2000-09-20 23:53",
        "scanned_by": "serveradmin"
      },
      "repo": "main"
    }
  ],
  "repo": "main"
},{
  "owner": "admin@123",
  "ipadd": "10.10.10.11",
  "servername": "demoserver2.admin.com",
  "Status": "live",
  "config": [
    {
      "ipadd": "10.10.10.10",
      "scan": {
        "last_scan_date": "2000-10-10 23:53",
        "auto_scan": [
            {
            "auto_scan_date": "2000-10-11 23:53" 
            }
            ],
        "scan_status": "Enable",
        "enable_datetime": "2000-09-20 23:53",
        "scanned_by": "serveradmin"
      },
      "repo": "main"
    }
  ],
  "repo": "main"
}]
```

**Looking for below the output**

```
servername| ipadd| last_scan_date| auto_scan_date| scan_status| enable_datetime
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
demoserver1.admin.com|10.10.10.10|2000-10-10 23:53|2000-10-11 23:53| Enable|2000-09-20 23:53
```

Answer (score 0):

Record path should point to the list you want to flatten, so in this case `auto_scan`. For each list level you cross in your JSON data, you add a nested list in `record_path`:

```
df = pd.json_normalize(data, record_path=['config', ['scan', 'auto_scan']])
```

Output:

```
     auto_scan_date
0  2000-10-11 23:53
1  2000-10-11 23:53
```

Then you must supply the `meta` argument to get all the other columns you want:

```
df = pd.json_normalize(data, record_path=['config', ['scan', 'auto_scan']], meta=['servername', 'ipadd', ['config', 'scan', 'last_scan_date'], ['config', 'scan', 'scan_status'], ['config', 'scan', 'enable_datetime']])

df.T
```

Output:

```
                                                 0                      1
auto_scan_date                    2000-10-11 23:53       2000-10-11 23:53
servername                   demoserver1.admin.com  demoserver2.admin.com
ipadd                                  10.10.10.10            10.10.10.11
config.scan.last_scan_date        2000-10-10 23:53       2000-10-10 23:53
config.scan.scan_status                     Enable                 Enable
config.scan.enable_datetime       2000-09-20 23:53       2000-09-20 23:53
```

To get the exact result you asked for, lets finish with some columns renaming / reordering:

```
df = df.rename({'config.scan.last_scan_date': 'last_scan_date', 'config.scan.scan_status': 'scan_status', 'config.scan.enable_datetime': 'enable_datetime'}, axis=1)
df = df[['servername', 'ipadd', 'last_scan_date', 'auto_scan_date', 'scan_status', 'enable_datetime']]

df.T
```

Output:

```
                                     0                      1
servername       demoserver1.admin.com  demoserver2.admin.com
ipadd                      10.10.10.10            10.10.10.11
last_scan_date        2000-10-10 23:53       2000-10-10 23:53
auto_scan_date        2000-10-11 23:53       2000-10-11 23:53
scan_status                     Enable                 Enable
enable_datetime       2000-09-20 23:53       2000-09-20 23:53
```

Answer (score 0):

your data, json_data

```
json_data = [
    {
    "owner": "admin@123",
    "ipadd": "10.10.10.10",
    "servername": "demoserver1.admin.com",
    "Status": "live",
    "config": [
        {
            "ipadd": "10.10.10.10",
            "scan": {
                "last_scan_date": "2000-10-10 23:53",
                "auto_scan": [
                    {
                        "auto_scan_date": "2000-10-11 23:53"
                    }
                ],
                "scan_status": "Enable",
                "enable_datetime": "2000-09-20 23:53",
                "scanned_by": "serveradmin"
            },
            "repo": "main"
        }
    ],
    "repo": "main"
    },
    {
    "owner": "admin@123",
    "ipadd": "10.10.10.11",
    "servername": "demoserver2.admin.com",
    "Status": "live",
    "config": [
        {
            "ipadd": "10.10.10.10",
            "scan": {
                "last_scan_date": "2000-10-10 23:53",
                "auto_scan": [
                    {
                        "auto_scan_date": "2000-10-11 23:53"
                    }
                ],
                "scan_status": "Enable",
                "enable_datetime": "2000-09-20 23:53",
                "scanned_by": "serveradmin"
            },
            "repo": "main"
        }
    ],
    "repo": "main"
    }
]
```

and you can try something like this:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame(
        {"servername": [data['servername'] for data in json_data],
         "ipadd": [data['config'][0]['ipadd'] for data in json_data],
         "last_scan_date": [data['config'][0]['scan']['last_scan_date'] for data in json_data],
         "auto_scan_date": [data['config'][0]['scan']['auto_scan'][0]['auto_scan_date'] for data in json_data],
         "scan_status": [data['config'][0]['scan']['scan_status'] for data in json_data],
         "enable_datetime": [data['config'][0]['scan']['enable_datetime'] for data in json_data]
        })
print(df.head())

servername        ipadd    last_scan_date    auto_scan_date scan_status   enable_datetime
0  demoserver1.admin.com  10.10.10.10  2000-10-10 23:53  2000-10-11 23:53      Enable  2000-09-20 23:53
1  demoserver2.admin.com  10.10.10.10  2000-10-10 23:53  2000-10-11 23:53      Enable  2000-09-20 23:53
```

Answer (score 0):

One simple approach is to use [`flatten_json`](https://pypi.org/project/flatten-json/) to flatten the json data. Pass the flattened data to pandas. When you *`print the commented df`* in the code snippet, you will see all the columns with record paths as headers. Rename the columns you are interested in and select them as your desired df.

```py
from flatten_json import flatten

flattened_data = [flatten(d, '.') for d in json_data]
df = pd.DataFrame(flattened_data)
# print(df)
df = df.rename(
    columns={
        'config.0.scan.last_scan_date': 'last_scan_date',
        'config.0.scan.auto_scan.0.auto_scan_date': 'auto_scan_date',
        'config.0.scan.scan_status': 'scan_status',
        'config.0.scan.enable_datetime': 'enable_datetime'
    })

df = df[[
  'servername', 'ipadd', 'last_scan_date', 'auto_scan_date', 'scan_status', 'enable_datetime'
]]

print(df)
```

If you prefer using [`json_normalize`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.json_normalize.html), you will need to provide an `ordered` lists which json_normalize will chain as a path to get your desired values, so the chained path becomes the column name, with the help of the `record_path` and `meta` parameters. You can then rename the columns and finally re-order the dataframe. Both approaches will produce the same output.

```py
df = pd.json_normalize(
            data,
            record_path=['config', 'scan', 'auto_scan'],
            meta=[
               'servername', 'ipadd',
               ['config', 'scan', 'last_scan_date'],
               ['config', 'scan', 'scan_status'],
               ['config', 'scan', 'enable_datetime']
            ])

df = df.rename(
    columns={
        'config.scan.last_scan_date': 'last_scan_date',
        'config.scan.auto_scan.auto_scan_date': 'auto_scan_date',
        'config.scan.scan_status': 'scan_status',
        'config.scan.enable_datetime': 'enable_datetime'
    })

df = df[[
  'servername', 'ipadd', 'last_scan_date', 'auto_scan_date', 'scan_status', 'enable_datetime'
]]

print(df)
```

---

```
              servername        ipadd    last_scan_date    auto_scan_date scan_status   enable_datetime
0  demoserver1.admin.com  10.10.10.10  2000-10-10 23:53  2000-10-11 23:53      Enable  2000-09-20 23:53
1  demoserver2.admin.com  10.10.10.11  2000-10-10 23:53  2000-10-11 23:53      Enable  2000-09-20 23:53
```